# Как очистить список неотслеживаемых файлов в git?

Tags: git

Ввожу git status, в итоге вижу несколько неослеживаемых файлов. Мне не нужно их коммитить, и удалять тоже не хочу. Как просто очистить этот список? Чтобы они не отображались при вводе git status.

Comment: Добавить в `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если файл не попал в индекс то его просто надо добавить в файл `.gitignore`,
если же попал то после добавления в `.gitignore` надо убрать из индекса следующей командой:
`git rm --cached file`